# Repacking monads -- any generic way?

Tags: haskell, monads

Given two monads, `Monad m` and `Monad n`, I would like to transform `m (n a)` into `n (m a)`. But there seems to be no generic way because both `(>>=)` and `return` deals with only one monad type, and although `(>>=)` allows extracting content from a monad, you must pack them back to the same monad type so it can be a result value.

However, if we set `m` to a fixed type, the job becomes easy. Take `Maybe` as an example:

```
reorder :: (Monad n) => Maybe (n a) -> n (Maybe a)
reorder Nothing = return Nothing
reorder (Just x) = do
    x' <- x
    return $ Just x'
```

Or a list:

```
reorder :: (Monad n) => [n a] -> n [a]
reorder [] = return []
reorder (x:xs) = do
    x'  <- x
    xs' <- reorder xs
    return (x':xs')
```

Not hard to see, we've got a pattern here. To be more obvious, write it in a `Applicative` way, and it's no more than applying the data constructor to each element:

```
reorder (Just x) = Just <$> x
reorder (x:xs) = (:) <$> x <*> (reorder xs)
```

My question is: does a haskell typeclass already exist to describe such operations, or do I have to invent the wheel myself?

I had a brief search in the GHC documentation, and found nothing useful for this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Data.Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html) provides what you are looking for:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

GHC even provides support for automatically deriving instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) 
  deriving(Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

Comment: This, of course, only works when your outer type constructor is a `Traversable` (not all `Monad`s are). The bonus is that the inner one only has to be `Applicative`.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search on hoogle for `(Monad m, Monad n) => m (n a) -> n (m a)` showed me that there are several functions that (roughly) comply with the signature you're looking for:

1. [`Data.Traversable.sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence);
2. [`Data.Traversable.sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA);
3. [Contro.Monad.sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence) (also exported by `Prelude`).

Both `[a]` and `Maybe a` are instances of traversable, so your reorder functions are just applications of `Data.Traversable.sequence`. One could write, in example:

```
ghci> (Data.Traversable.sequence $ Just (return 1)) :: IO (Maybe Int)
Just 1
it :: Maybe Int

ghci> (Data.Traversable.sequence $ Just ([1])) :: [Maybe Int]
[Just 1]
it :: [Maybe Int]

ghci> (Data.Traversable.sequence $ [Just 1]) :: Maybe [Int]
Just [1]
it :: Maybe [Int]
```

Please note however that the specific class declaration is `class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t`, and if you look also at the types of the other two functions, it does not seems like what you're looking for could possibly be done in a generic way for all monads `m` and `n` without restrictions/preconditions.

Answer (score 4):

It can't be done in general: a good example of a monad that can't do this is the reader (or function) monad. That would require the following function to be definable:

```
impossible :: (r -> IO a) -> IO (r -> a)
```

It's not straightforward to prove that a function *cannot* be implemented. But intuitively, the problem is that whatever `IO` has to be done in the value returned has to be done *before we know what the `r` parameter is*. So `impossible readFile` would have to yield a pure function `FilePath -> String` before it knew which files to open. Clearly, at least, `impossible` can't do what you'd want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Monads can commute in that way. Edward Kmett's [distributive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.2.0.1) package provides a typeclass `Distributive` for type constructors that is similar to what you desire (simplified):

```
class Functor g => Distributive g where
  distribute  :: Functor f => f (g a) -> g (f a)
  collect     :: Functor f => (a -> g b) -> f a -> g (f b)
```

Default definitions are provided for `distribute` and `collect`, written in terms of each other. I found this package by [searching hayoo for the desired type signature](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html).